# vertically centering image in jQuery Cycle (responsive)

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, vertical-alignment, cycle

I am trying to create a image rotator using jQuery Cycle. The image has some responsive sizing components to it (not a fully responsive site at this stage...I know...this is still in development). Essentially I want the image to center as it sizes up with the browser within a space with a defined height (needs to be viewed on a large screen to see this). I can get the image to vertically center without the rotator functionality, but my jQuery function that determines positioning for the image executes on page load and on browser resize...not when the image rotates with Cycle. It looks ok initially, but resize the browser a bit and you will see the image shift down.

This is the code for vertical centering:

```
var imageHeight, overlap, container = $('.banner'); 

function centerImage() {
    imageHeight = container.find('img').height();
    overlap = (520 - imageHeight) / 2;
    container.find('img').css('margin-top', overlap);
}

$(window).on("load resize", centerImage);
```

Just in case, this is my Cycle function call:

```
$('#banner_items').cycle({ 
    speed:  1000,
    timeout: 3000,
    slideResize: 0,
    slideExpr: '.banner'        
});
```

The link to the site is:
www.envisiondemo.com/planview

Any suggestions for how to make this work together?

Comment: Have you tried resizing the elements that contain the image (or putting a DIV in), and having the image size be based on that? Then when you resize the page, the outer container element resizes with the screen. Since the images all size to this container element it would be consistent even if you switched images.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting and how it would resolve the vertical centering issue. I'm not having trouble resizing the image. Despite the container, I need the image to vertically center in unison with the Cycle rotation.

Comment: You said you can get one of them to center, but when the image changes it doesn't center? Center a container instead, size and switch the images relative to and within that one container. If they all size to the same container, and the container sizes properly regardless of which image is inside of it, that should work. Center the container within the area you were trying to size the images in, resize that container as necessary, and center the images within the container using CSS. Does that make sense? Do you have a simplified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the issue?

Comment: If you don't touch the browser, the images center during the rotation just fine. The issue happens when you resize during the rotation it seems. This happens somewhat unpredictably. I've been able to add the function call to Cycle so it does center again if this issue happens, but you still occasionally see the jump. What I can't figure out is why the image pushes down at all. There isn't any styling that would push it down that I know of. When you use the two script independently, the image never shifts down. Thanks for your help!